# JUnit Test for Reciprocals

Tags: java, junit

I have a code that takes the reciprocal of a rational number. I have a constructor as well. This is what I have:

```
private int num;
private int den;
public Rational(int numIn, int denIn) {
    num = numIn;
    den = denIn;
}
public String reciprocal() {
    return den + "/" + num;
}
```

I want to write a JUnit Test for this code. This is what I have so far, but it keeps failing:

```
int num = 7;
int den = 5;
@Test
public void reciprocal() {
    String answer = 7 + "/" +5;
    assertTrue(answer == 5 + "/" + 7);
}
```

How can I make it so that, with the code I have, the JUnit Test will come out as not a failure?

Comment: Within the test you need to construct an instance of the class you want to test, `Rational`, call the method under test and then assert its result

Comment: Also, use `assertEquals` instead of `assertTrue` so that it calls the `equals()` method.

Comment: Perhaps +5 is not acting as you expect (+ can act as a unary operator).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your test is not testing anything. Generally a test needs to

- setup a test case (e.g. construct an instance of `Rational` under test specific conditions, that is with 7 and 5)
- execute a method/functionality to be tested (call `.reciprocal` on the constructed object)
- assert the result if it is returned (the reciprocal value) or a state change if the method returns void and has side effects against some expected value(s).

For your case this means:

```
@Test
public void reciprocal() {
    Rational rat = new Rational(7, 5);
    String res = rat.reciprocal();
    assertEquals(5 + "/" + 7, res);
}
```